Does WhatsApp use data from an inactive SIM card?
I associated my WhatsApp account with a Canadian mobile/cell number. I am now in UK without any local SIM card installed.
If I use WhatsApp outside of Wi-Fi, will it try to use/charge the Canadian cell number (i.e., high roaming charges)?


I associated my Whatsapp account with a Canadian mobile/cell number. I am now in UK with no local SIM installed.

Linking your phone number to your WhatsApp account is to help users find you (by username and mobile number) as well a as for Meta/WhatsApp to authenticate you, including login and identity verification
It is not used for billing nor can it activate services like (roaming) phone calls or SMS Messaging

If I use Whatsapp outside of Wi-Fi, will it try to use/charge the Canadian cell number (i.e. high roaming charges)?

It can’t. Full stop.  If you have an inactive SIM, you can’t utilize the carriers network. It also cannot enable service features like roaming unless you enabled it with your Canadian carrier.
You said you didn’t have a local SIM installed but never mentioned it you had the Canadian SIM/eSIM installed.  If you cannot make phone calls or send SMS messages with Wi-Fi disabled, then you’re not roaming and it is impossible to incur those charges. If you can, you enabled it with the carrier as part of your plan contract and you will be billed for that usage should you do it outside of Wi-Fi.
This applies to every app and isn’t limited to WhatsApp.   It only cares that it’s connected, not how you’re connected.

I second this. For privacy reasons, I have registered my WhatsApp account with an otherwise unused number, on an otherwise unused Phone. The phone and SIM are now in my drawer, powered off and separated. I never had any problems sending/receiving WhatsApp messages with my primary phone, be it over cellular service or WiFi.

Your iPhone will tell you if any SIM card (physical or eSIM) are active—so as long as that's showing off or inactive, you won't get any data charges.

Use cellular data on your iPhone or iPad

Some services (like Apple messages) needs to activate via an SMS message once and then keep working over Wi-Fi even if the SMS service is disabled or expired or off.
As long as your app works, you should be good over Wi-Fi and you'll want to check how to change your phone as an identifier (username) if it's needed to continue using the service long term.
